# Swagger: How do I represent a choice?

Tags: api, swagger

I have a field that can take either ObjectType1, ObjectType2

```
{
    "field":[ObjectType1 | ObjectType2]
}
```

for e.g. an address can be a street address, a PO Box.

```
{
    "address":{
        "street":"123 anystreet",
        "city":"Any Town"
    }
}
```

OR

```
{
    "address":{
        "pobox":"6554",
        "zip" :"1234"
    }
}
```

How do I represent/describe this in swagger?  Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unless the variations have a common field that allows you to know which of the objects it is and in that case you can use inheritance/polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks Ron, When I define the type as base type the Swagger model displays just the base type.  I want to display inherited types as well so that a developer can decide which one of the sub-types to use. Is there a working example?

Comment: There isn't because that's not yet supported by the tools. One of the features to be included in the next major release hopefully.

Comment: Ron, Appreciate it.  Look forward to this new release.